# Can you turn a laptop into a nothing-but-keyboard connected to a PC via wire?

Tags: networking, laptop, keyboard

I have an old laptop which I enjoy typing on. I have been using Synergy to use it as a keyboard for my pc at both work and home.

It's been a year and I can confirm that it is the only purpose this laptop serves. A keyboard. Synergy sometimes lags even with both system connected to a same router via wire (Don't think this is a connection issue but more of a OS/SW issue)

Laptop is running Linux(Elementary OS).

I would very much like to:

1. Take the screen apart and just carry the underpart
2. Power it with a existing power adapter
3. Connect laptop to a PC via ??? (Some sort of wired connection)
4. Turn on the laptop using the same power button
5. Once powered on, it is automatically recognized by the PC as an input device (Wire connection).

Would this be possible?

I do not want to use KVM switch or any other wireless methods currently available. Above steps are exactly how I would like them to perform.

Thanks!

Comment: Thats not going to happen without significant hackery, both in hardware and software.

Answer (score 0):

So you want to connect your Laptop to your PC using a wire in order to use it as a keyboard... a USB keyboard is starting at something like 5€ and is going to work reliably?

Do you already have a setup that allows you to just turn on your laptop and it automatically connects using Synergy? If not you should first get that going. Don't forget that you want to patch that system occasionally or have a look at the reason why Synergy didn't start. So make sure the external VGA port or similar works.

Look at your Manual for information on how to remove/detach the screen. Also setup the BIOS accordingly beforehand. Have a look whenever you can set it to "Resume Power on Power loss" that way you'd be able to just put it on a Master/Slave power cord. A script which detects whenever it's running on AC power or battery could help you shut it down properly after you shutdown the "master" (the PC) on said power cord. As for actually using the power button you'll have to solder something yourself. You could try to just split off, off your PCs power button and attach it to the Laptops power button but this is going to be very delicate connection. Depending on the construction of your Laptops power button you will not be able to properly attach.